# Why value is not populated inside the input in mat datepicker?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-datetimepicker

I have current template:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="my_date" 
        [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker" #myDate="ngModel"        
        [(ngModel)]="myDateValue" id="my_date" required>                                        
    <mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>                                                                                
    <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
```

The init happen when loading the component:

```
public myDateValue: string;
    this.myDateValue= myMonth.toString() + "\/" + myDay.toString() + "\/" + myYear.toString();
```

When printing the date to the console I get to see it in the FormControl
value.
But when the page load the date is not populate into the textbox?

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: edit this stackblitz example with your issue : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker

Comment: for myMonth,myDay,myYear your directly assigning the values??? please share whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to solve this issue I had to change the myDateValue to type Date.
That's solved the problem.
mat datepicker require the field to be type Date.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was that the binding to the value was like that:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="my_date" 
    [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker" #myDate="ngModel"        
    [value]="myDateValue|date" id="my_date" required>                                        
<mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>                                                                                
<mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
```

i removed the- | date

and then it worked

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="my_date" 
    [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker" #myDate="ngModel"        
    [value]="myDateValue" id="my_date" required>                                        
<mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>                                                                                
<mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
```